Bounds on $3$-smooth numbers

Denote by $\Psi(x,3)$ the number of $3$-smooth numbers at most $x$; that is, the number of integers $n\le x$ with only primes $2$ and $3$ in its factorisation. What is the asymptotic error term?

It is easy to see that $$\Psi(x,3)=\#\{2^a3^b\le x: a,b\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$
We know that the asymptotic for this is $$\Psi(x,3)\sim \frac{\log^2x}{2\log 2\log 3},$$ but I am unsure about what the error term is. To obtain this asymptotic, one can essentially look at a triangle with base $\log_2x$ and height $\log_3x$ and then we are just counting lattice points. The error term comes from lattice points which lie close to, or on, the diagonal. So my question is: (1) What is the known error term? and (2) Can it be improved? How?

The full expansion is as follows
$$
\Psi(x,3)={\log^2x\over2\log2\log3}+{\log x\over2\log2}+{\log x\over2\log3}+O\left(\log x\over\log\log x\right).\tag1
$$
In general, let $N(\eta)$ be the number of solutions $(u,v)\in\mathbb Z^2$ for which
$$
u\ge0,\quad v\ge0,\quad \omega u+\omega'v\le\eta.
$$
Then there is
$$
N(\eta)={\eta^2\over2\omega\omega'}+{\eta\over2\omega}+{\eta\over2\omega'}+R(\eta),
$$
where $R(\eta)=o(\eta)$ when $\omega/\omega'$ is irrational and $R(\eta)\ne o(\eta)$ when $\omega/\omega'$ is rational. For the particular case $\Psi(x,3)$ (i.e. $\omega=\log2$, $\omega'=\log3$, and $\eta=\log x$), one can improve $R(\eta)=o(\eta)$ to $R(\eta)=O(\eta/\log\eta)$, which explains why (1) has the error term $O(\log x/\log\log x)$.
For a detailed explanation of all these, see §5 of G. H. Hardy's book Ramanujan: Twelve lectures suggested by his life and work.

Thank you for this detailed answer! Is the bound $R(\eta)$ improvable? Or do we know what the implied constant is? i.e. do we know a value of $C$ such that $R(\eta)\le C\frac{\eta}{\log\eta}$?

If you follow Hardy's arguments closely, you can obtain a specific value for $C>0$. Regarding improvement, you need results concerning Diophantine approximations
